# How can I keep a list of scripts

Tags: powershell

Last week a colleague asked if I had a script to get permissions to a folder. I knew I had one but for the life of me, I could not remember where it was located.

This got me thinking, how can I keep a list of all scripts I have and where they a located?

So... I came here for advice to this question?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nuisance. This is not an on-topic question for SO. Perhaps taking the tour again would help. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a github private repository, it's a little bit of work at the start to class and write description, but it will definitely help you to the future.

Good luck anyway

Comment: thanks,  how do i then view the description?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some tools that help you with your own workflow you can write .bat or .ps1 scripts and put them into a directory that you load into your windows %PATH% environment.

For example i have this script
C:\helpful_scripts\git-tag.bat
with

```
@echo off
set /p vers="Enter version tag (rel-x.x.x or vx.x.x)(QUIT with q) : "
if "%vers%" == "q" (exit 1)
git tag %vers%
git push origin %vers%
echo "done"
```

because i need to make a lot of version and release tags to my git repositories and don't want to type so much.

And therefore i put it into my PATH environment so i can use `git-tag` anywhere.

For other sourcecode and scripts you dont want to execute but just organize you need to make a kind of organization structure yourself. For example a wiki like .md file in github. Good luck

Comment: What I'm to have is a list, it can be in either HTML, CSV or even TXT. It should have something like e.g.

`Script Name - Get-ACL
Location - c:\Git\Powershell\Get-ACL; Github/Powershell/Get-ACL
Description - This script is used to obtain the ACL of a specific folder...`

I don't know if there's already a tool or script that help me create such a list.

Comment: I'd like to recommend @su7 answer. Head over to github.com and start a new project. Create a file named "README.md" and use Markdown Syntax. It is pretty simple. Some examples: `# title` or `## subtitle` make big written titles. Just entering text is text. Using backticks like ` `` ` surrounding text with 1 or 3 backticks in front and at the end make code-blocks. Using `*` in front and at the end of text makes it italic and/or bold style. `*thisisbold*`. Simply adding a dash in front of a line start a list of contents. Like this  `- blabla`